# Override .NET Core MVC default int validation message

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

Within my app I have a form which asks a user for month and year. These are currently setup to be `int?` but when a user enters a none int to the input text field, it throws the default error message of 'The value 'seven' is not valid for Month.'

Is there a way I can customise this to be whatever content I would like it to be?
Field in question are

```
public int? VisitMonth { get; set; }
public int? VisitYear { get; set; }
```

I am using [Range()] to validate the value is 1-12 when they do enter an int which works as expected.

Comment: You might look at using Fluent Validation, it allows for creating custom validation rules and messages. Info at https://fluentvalidation.net/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `string` instead of `int?` and create a regular expression (use `RegularExpression` attribute to your property) that accepts words and numbers between 1-12 (as in your range). On the server side, try to do a parse with `Int32.TryParse`. If the parse is successful then you have a numeric value, otherwise it's just a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the validation error message by using the ErrorMessage property. Code as below:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid Month")]
    [Range(1,12,ErrorMessage ="Entered Month is inValid")]
    public int? VisitMonth { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a valid Year")]
    [Range(1, 12, ErrorMessage = "Entered Year is inValid")]
    public int? VisitYear { get; set; }
```

The output:

[image]